# What is Virtual Texturing?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently saw a feature in Unity's Player Settings named Virtual Texturing. I tried looking for Unity Documentation but couldn't find much.

Unity Editor:

[image]

Can anyone explain what this feature is and how it works in Unity. More importantly, should I enable it?

Comment: It's right there in the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/svt-streaming-virtual-texturing.html).

Comment: Was it so wrong to ask such a question on this platform? Why I'm being voted negatively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ##### Unity User Manual 2021.3 (LTS)
>
> ## [Streaming Virtual Texturing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/svt-streaming-virtual-texturing.html)
>
> **This feature is experimental and not ready for production use. The feature and documentation might be changed or removed in the future.**
>
> Streaming Virtual Texturing (SVT) is a feature that reduces GPU memory
> usage and texture loading times when you have many high resolution
> textures in your Scene . It splits textures into tiles, and
> progressively uploads these tiles to GPU memory when they are needed.

Unity is playing catchup on this front with Unreal Engine's [Virtual Texturing](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/RenderingAndGraphics/VirtualTexturing/) feature which is available since at least 4.26.

> More importantly, should I enable it?

You can enable it and play with it, see how it behaves, but since it's experimental it is not recommended in a production environment.